# Why can't I use the setLayout method from the class Frame with a BorderLayout?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, frame, border-layout

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BorderLayout {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("This is a Border Layout example!");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); //ERROR HERE...

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I see your mistake:
You name your class BorderLayout, so `new BorderLayout()` instantiate a new object of your class and not the wanted BorderLayout.

Comment: Thanks man !!
I used it the same with other classes and it worked fine. And I had been unable to identify the mistake.